# How does it sound if a guy says "dans mes jupons"?

Tags: expressions

I jokingly said to my friend who was putting a damper on my shopping spree with her constant whining:

> C'est trop te demander de me laisser faire mon shopping peinard ? Toi qui pleurniches **dans mes jupons**, je pourrais carrément m'en passer ! Starbucks ne risque pas de prendre la fuite !

I wonder if it was appropriate for me, a guy, to use the expression "dans mes jupons", even if I wasn't talking about a *real* skirt?

Any suggestion for a more *gender-neutral* alternative to jokingly and pejoratively describe a sissy whining nag?

Comment: I concur with the answer that says it is appropriate. On the same idea, I have a (male) friend who keeps on saying "ça fait mal aux seins",, and it seems more and more teenage girls say "ça me casse les c***lles !". I believe that such idioms are doomed to lose their gender denotation when they become popular.

Comment: @Greg I was concerned that "dans mes jupons" might not be established enough as an idiom to be used *gender-free*, especially given that there is no entry for the expression, even in Wiki.

Comment: maybe you could find it under the variant *dans les jupes* ? At least that is how Larousse has it: http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/jupes/45179/locution?q=jupes#173439

Answer (score 3):

*Dans mes jupons* **is not** gender neutral. If the expression is used by a man, it is done humorously.

There is a close but not strictly equivalent alternative that can be used for everyone:

> collé aux basques

See [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29027/does-this-particular-use-of-basques-carry-a-pejorative-condescending-connota/29033#29033) for details. Edit: that question was yours too...

Comment: En plus de "collé aux basques" il y aurait aussi "dans mes pattes" mais aucun des deux ne va vraiment aussi bien avec "pleurnicher" que "dans mes jupons"

Answer (score -1):

It is entirely appropriate. There's nothing gendered about the expression in Modern French, though of course nothing prevents someone from making a transvestite joke after being told that.