# Pourquoi l'homonymie serait-elle « déplaisante » avec le gentilé « Basque » au féminin ?

Tags: grammaire, genre, origine-ou-raison, homonymes, gentilés

Dans une [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/41170) on présente le gentilé feminin *Basquaise*. Au TLFi on dit dans une remarque :

> Au féminin, pour éviter l'homonymie **déplaisante** avec [*basque*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/basque/0),
>   l'usage tend à imposer la forme *Basquaise*.
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé, « [basque](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/basque/1) », je souligne ]

Peut-on expliquer pourquoi l'homonymie est-elle « déplaisante » ? Si c'était à cause de l'acception que l'on trouve dans l'emploi au [féminin pluriel](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/basques/8244#locution) « se pendre, s'accrocher aux basques de qqn. » (TLFi), est-ce alors moins déplaisant au féminin singulier ? Considérant les contextes d'emploi différents entre le gentilé et le vêtement, et l'emploi au pluriel dans l'expression, au final en quoi est-ce moins déplaisant au masculin : pourquoi l'adéquation du genre grammatical serait-elle requise pour que ce soit *déplaisant* ici ?

Comment: La fierté des Basques est enracinée dans l’attachement au Pays-Basque et à une langue vernaculaire non indo-européenne (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basque), alors comparer les femmes de ce pays à un morceau de tissu en ergotant sur la grammaire …

Comment: Y a-t-il vraiment des gens qui savent ce qu'est *précisément* une basque, voire qui emploient ce mot en dehors de l'expression (déjà pas très commune) "lâcher/coller aux basques"?

Comment: @ho2o2hh2o … c’était seulement une touche d’humour pour indiquer que la seule langue que je pratique se vit *surtout* en-dehors de la grammaire, filtre réducteur qui enferme dans des concepts une réalité trop grande pour elle, concepts que l’expression poétique bouscule souvent et ignore parfois  … j’espère que ma réponse éclairera vos recherches.

Comment: Le *J’allons* que l’on entend parfois dans les chansons de ces marins qui embarquaient à bord des terre-neuvas ou cap-horniers biens gréés… loin des arguties germanopratines, ils savaient que voir les colères de Poséidon en face c’était  boire leur dernière tasse … dans l’oralité des vents qui hurlent ou rugissent se perdent les mots savants, seul le Verbe permet de gagner la route du retour chez soi … *[fin de digression sur* aller]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cette homonymie pouvait peut-être encore être utilisée pour justifier *Basquaise* en 1975 dans un dictionnaire de la langue du XIXᵉ et XXᵉ siècle mais ne tient plus aujourd'hui car le sens et le genre de l'acception *basque* en question est essentiellement perdu, ce mot n'étant plus vraiment utilisé que dans l'expression *[coller aux basques](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29027/does-this-particular-use-of-basques-carry-a-pejorative-condescending-connota)* où ni l'un ni l'autre ne sont plus perçus.

On peut d'ailleurs remarquer que *Basquaise* semble être en perte de vitesse face à *Basque* depuis les années 80 :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

L’écrit avec **B** ne pose pas de problème, mais  *basque* étant épicène, l’adjectif utilisé sera *basquais·e*, surtout pour les genres.

En fait, l’adjectif *basque* n’est applicable que pour le pays Basque — le petit Robert.

> Les habitants *basques* de cette ville du Nord … (hommes et femmes, facilité de langage par rattachement au Pays basque, on devrait écrire *basquais·e·s*).
>
> Madame Untelle, *basquaise* de Bayonne … (comme bayonnaise).
>
> L’adjectif *[basquais](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Basquais)* ne s’emploie que pour les humains, il est tombé en désuétude.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais lu ou entendu *poulet basquais* ni d'ailleurs *basquais* au masculin. C'est le plus souvent *poulet basquaise* ou sinon, *poulet à la basquaise*, *poulet à la mode basquaise*, *poulet à la façon basquaise* avec une majuscule ou pas à *basquaise*. On retrouve le même schéma avec *tomates à la provençale*, *sauce à la périgourdine*, *spätzles à l'alsacienne*, etc.

Comment: De rien. À propos, mon pronom préféré est *tu*... :-)

Comment: https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/est-ce-quon-se-tutoie

Comment: @jlliagre … *tu* as bien fait de me faire corriger *basquais* dans ma réponse … et découvrir que le *tu* est scriptural sur ce site (-: pourvu que ce ne soit pas une ‘anglicismisation’ du *you* :-)

Comment: *Scriptural* ? C'est vrai que j'aime les jeux d'écriture ;-)